# How to add a specific element from an object array to session Storage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code that converts an array of strings into an array of objects and then display them along with their details in a grid of product cards:

```
let allHoodies = [
['Hoodie', 'Purple', 'Cotton', '$39.99', 'image/items/hoodies/hoodie(1).jpg'],
['Hoodie', 'Blue', 'Cotton', '$39.99', 'image/items/hoodies/hoodie(2).jpg'],
['Hoodie', 'Green', 'Cotton', '$39.99', 'image/items/hoodies/hoodie(3).jpg']
]

allHoodies.forEach((element, index) => {
    let obj = {}
    obj.type = element[0]
    obj.color = element[1]
    obj.material = element[2]
    obj.price = element[3]
    obj.imagesrc = element[4]
    allHoodies[index] = obj
})

//Evaluating each hoodie and displaying its information in HTML
allHoodies.forEach(function (hoodie) {
    let card = `
        <div class="card">
            <img class="product-image" src="${hoodie.imagesrc}">
            <h1 class="product-type">${hoodie.type}</h1>
            <p>Color: ${hoodie.color}</p>
            <p>${hoodie.material} <a href="#" id="addToSessionStorage" onclick="">Read more</a> </p>
            <p class="price">${hoodie.price}</p>
            <p><button>Buy</button></p>
        </div>
    `;

    // Add the card to the page
    document.getElementById('product-container').innerHTML += card;
});
```

how can I add the specific object to session storage upon clicking "**Read more**"?

put together in: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mozzenberg/fyruvL16/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
let allHoodies = [
['Hoodie', 'Purple', 'Cotton', '$39.99', 'image/items/hoodies/hoodie(1).jpg'],
['Hoodie', 'Blue', 'Cotton', '$39.99', 'image/items/hoodies/hoodie(2).jpg'],
['Hoodie', 'Green', 'Cotton', '$39.99', 'image/items/hoodies/hoodie(3).jpg']
]



allHoodies.forEach((element, index) => {
    let obj = {}
    obj.type = element[0]
    obj.color = element[1]
    obj.material = element[2]
    obj.price = element[3]
    obj.imagesrc = element[4]
    allHoodies[index] = obj;
})




allHoodies.forEach(function (hoodie) {
    let card = `
        <div class="card">
            <img class="product-image" src="${hoodie.imagesrc}">
            <h1 class="product-type">${hoodie.type}</h1>
            <p>Color: ${hoodie.color}</p>
            <p>${hoodie.material} <a href="#" class="addToSessionStorage" onclick="">Read more</a></p>
            <p class="price">${hoodie.price}</p>
            <p><button>Buy</button></p>
        </div>
    `;
    
    

    // Add the card to the page
    document.getElementById('product-container').innerHTML += card;
});


[...document.querySelectorAll(".addToSessionStorage")].forEach((readMoreBtn, index) => {
    readMoreBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   
    sessionStorage.setItem(index, JSON.stringify(allHoodies[index]));
  })
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would add an `id` to each `hoodie` object. You could use the `index` for this. Then you'll need to fill in the `onclick` handler with something like `addToStorage(${hoodie.id})`. In the `addToStorage` function you can do the actual addition of the item to storage.

Updated your fiddle and posted it below:

```js
let allHoodies = [
  ['Hoodie', 'Purple', 'Cotton', '$39.99', 'image/items/hoodies/hoodie(1).jpg'],
  ['Hoodie', 'Blue', 'Cotton', '$39.99', 'image/items/hoodies/hoodie(2).jpg'],
  ['Hoodie', 'Green', 'Cotton', '$39.99', 'image/items/hoodies/hoodie(3).jpg']
]

allHoodies.forEach((element, index) => {
  let obj = {}
  obj.id = index
  obj.type = element[0]
  obj.color = element[1]
  obj.material = element[2]
  obj.price = element[3]
  obj.imagesrc = element[4]
  allHoodies[index] = obj
})

//Evaluating each hoodie and displaying its information in HTML
allHoodies.forEach(function(hoodie) {
  let card = `
        <div class="card">
            <img class="product-image" src="${hoodie.imagesrc}">
            <h1 class="product-type">${hoodie.type}</h1>
            <p>Color: ${hoodie.color}</p>
            <p>${hoodie.material} <a href="#" onclick="addToStorage(${hoodie.id})">Read more</a> </p>
            <p class="price">${hoodie.price}</p>
            <p><button>Buy</button></p>
        </div>
    `;

  // Add the card to the page
  document.getElementById('product-container').innerHTML += card;
});

function addToStorage(id) {
  const hoodie = allHoodies[id]
  console.log(hoodie)
  // sessionStorage can only store strings
  // commented out because sessionStorage cannot be set in the SO environment
  // sessionStorage.setItem("someKey", JSON.stringify(hoodie))
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-type {
  color: #f2be1a;
}

.price {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.card button {
  outline: 0;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#product-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 30px;
}

.product-image {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="product-container"></div>
```

Comment: this is honestly perfect and it was exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!
Although, is there a way for me to use the data in the session storage again to display the specific item in a different page? here's what I tired to do [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mozzenberg/0eny7vfq/5/) @titus

Comment: You're welcome. The only issue you have in your new Fiddle is that you don't use the same key in `getItem` as you do in `setItem`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried doing something else but it still doesn't work for some reason, I'd really appreciate it if you can guide me, here's what I've done:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mozzenberg/0eny7vfq/15/)

Comment: When you retrieve the item from storage it will be a string. You need to convert it back to an object in order to access the attributes: `const productDetails = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("item"));`

Comment: You're a life saver. Thank you so much for everything, I hope you have an amazing rest of the day and keep being awesome